# Why is $(x'x)^{-1}x' = x(x'x)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, statistics, regression

If $(AB)'=B'A'$ then $(x'x)^{-1}x'$ should be equal to $x((x'x)^{-1})'$ . However most econometrics textbooks say that this is equal to $x(x'x)^{-1}$ . What happened to the transpose of $(x'x)^{-1}$? According to the rule it should have a transpose.

Comment: What does ' mean here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I think ' means transpose

Comment: Yes, it means transpose.

Comment: What is the source of this question, is it from a book? Since you're new, my advice is maybe you can clarify your question to avoid getting down voted so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=x'x$ and $b=a^{-1}$. Then $a'=(x'x)'=x'x''=x'x=a$ hence $b'=b$. Thus your suggestion to use the transpose of $(x'x)^{-1}$ and the practice of using $(x'x)^{-1}$ instead, are in fact equivalent.